# slack block add confirmation only for one option in static_select

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit, slack-dialog

Is it possible to have confirmation dialogue just on any one options from slack's static_select?

I'm at the situation where i have static_select drop-down with 3 options **send, duplicate, delete.**
And i just want confirmation dialogue to show up only when **delete** is selected. Right now it's showing for all options. Let me know if there's an alternative way around to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.